# MenuItem Style seems to be overwritten

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mahapps.metro

It seems that the menuitem style that I am attempting to use gets totally overwritten when I use ItemContainerStyle.

Here's an example of what happens when I use it:

[image]

However, when I don't use it, this is what I get:

[image]

I much prefer the look of the second menu, but it doesn't support dynamic menu creation due to not using ItemContainerStyle. What could possibly be overwriting the style? I'm using Mahapps Dark base and VS colors/styles.

Comment: Have you tried the [BasedOn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3656814/how-to-inherit-xaml-style-and-override-property-of-child-element) attribute on the `ItemContainerStyle` `Style`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base your custom `Style` on the `MetroMenuItem` style that comes with `MahApps`:

```
<Style TargetType="MenuItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource MetroMenuItem}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow" />
</Style>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I set up my project to use MahApps in the app.xaml, so the styles would be global. Any clue why this wouldn't automatically base off of that?

Comment: Why would it be? That's not how implicit style works.

Answer (score 1):

you should use BaseOn property in the ItemContainerStyle.

```
<ItemContainerStyle x:Key="MyContainerStyle" BaseOn="{DynamicResource MenuItemStyle}">Style here</ItemContainerStyle>
```